# Ciclo infinito al tratar de validar datos

Tags: c, scanf

Tengo un programa que te da unas opciones a eligir para calcular operaciones, cuando elijo la primera opción esta me va a sacar la raíz cuadrada de un numero.

Cuando entro en la función de la opción 1, e intento validar que la entrada introducida sea solo números y no letras o caracteres me genera un ciclo infinito preguntando lo mismo.

Esta es la funcion que utilizo para la parte de calcular la raíz de un numero, y aquí cuando intento validar me genera el ciclo infinito preguntado: 
**Ingrese un valor numerico para calcular la raiz de A**

```
void opcion1(void){
float A, K, i, aux,;
int awnser;
ask:
    printf("Ingrese un valor numerico para calcular la raiz de A\n");
    awnser = scanf("%f", &A);
if( awnser !=1 || awnser == EOF){ // not a number
    printf("Por favor introduce un dato numerico\n");
    goto ask;
}
if(A < 0 ){
    aux = -A;
    i = sqrt(aux);
    if(A == (int)A) printf("La raiz cuadrada de %.0f, es %.0fi", A, i);
    else printf("La raiz cuadrada de %.3f, es %.4fi", A, i);
}else{
    K = sqrt(A);
    printf("La raiz cuadrada de A es %.2f", K);
}
}
```

Así se ve la salida

```
Seleccione una opcion
Presione 1 para hallar la raiz de un numero
Presione 2 para intercambiar tres valores
Presione 3 para verificar si un estudiante esta aprobado o no
Presione 0 para salir
: 1
Ingrese un valor numerico para calcular la raiz de A
k
Por favor introduce un dato numerico
Ingrese un valor numerico para calcular la raiz de A
Por favor introduce un dato numerico
Ingrese un valor numerico para calcular la raiz de A
Por favor introduce un dato numerico
Ingrese un valor numerico para calcular la raiz de A
Por favor introduce un dato numerico
Ingrese un valor numerico para calcular la raiz de A
Por favor introduce un dato numerico
Ingrese un valor numerico para calcular la raiz de A
Por favor introduce un dato numerico
Ingrese un valor numerico para calcular la raiz de A
Por favor introduce un dato numerico
Ingrese un valor numerico para calcular la raiz de A
```

a que se debe este error?

Answer (score 1):

El problema radica en esta parte del código:

```
ask:
    printf("Ingrese un valor numerico para calcular la raiz de A\n");
    awnser = scanf("%f", &A);
if( awnser !=1 || awnser == EOF){ // not a number
    printf("Por favor introduce un dato numerico\n");
    goto ask;
}
```

Por ejemplo, si el usuario ingresa Hola Mundo, la función scanf retornará 0 porqué hubo un error, entonces como el búfer de entrada estándar quedo sucio, la próxima vez que se vuelva a pedir datos al usuario, scanf no se detendrá, porqué encontró caracteres que no son válidos para un valor decimal.
La solución es limpiar el búfer después del scanf.

```
    ask:
    printf("Ingrese un valor numerico para calcular la raiz de A\n");
    awnser = scanf("%f", &A);
    //Limpiamos el búfer hasta encontrar un caracter de nueva línea o hasta hallar el final del archivo (EOF).
    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
    if( awnser !=1 || awnser == EOF){ // not a number
        printf("Por favor introduce un dato numerico\n");
        goto ask;
    }
```

Hay una librería llamada PScanf que te permite validar los datos que el usuario ingrese.
Tu código con PScanf sería así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pscanf.h>
int main()
{
    float A, K, i, aux;
    dataread("%f", &A, "Ingrese un valor numerico para calcular la raiz de A\n");
    if(A < 0 ){
        aux = -A;
        i = sqrt(aux);
        if(A == (int)A) printf("La raiz cuadrada de %.0f, es %.0fi", A, i);
        else printf("La raiz cuadrada de %.3f, es %.4fi", A, i);
    }else{
        K = sqrt(A);
        printf("La raiz cuadrada de A es %.2f", K);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Con la macro dataread te valida todo automáticamente, no necesitas agregar ningún bucle adicional, ni limpiar el búfer del teclado.

Enlace de la librería:

[Library-PScanf](https://www.github.com/MrDave1999/pscanf.h)

**EDITO:**

Este código:

`while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);`

Es equivalente a:

```
while(1)
{
   ch = getchar();
   if(ch == '\n' || ch == EOF)
   {
        break;
   }
}
```

La diferencia es que el primero es un while sin implementación (que no tiene ningún código entre llaves), así te ahorras unas cuantas líneas y el segundo, si tiene una implementación.

Comment: Excelente, una sola cosa que tengo en duda es cuando colocas el while sin sentencias solo con las condiciones que significa o a que es equivalente. Estoy comenzando y es primera vez que veo esta forma de while. esta parte :            
 `while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);`

Comment: @KleiverMarcano Ya edité mi publicación, ahí respondo su inquietud.

Comment: muchas gracias!